# Android - Executar função com segundos de atraso

Tags: java, android

Minha dúvida é: como faço para que uma função seja executada segundos depois de outra?

**MainActivity.class**

```
public void onClick(View p1){
    //quero que essa função seja executada primeiro
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //e essa dois segundos depois

    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(it);   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o postDelayed:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Se estiver usando Java 8:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(() -> {
    Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(it);
}, 1000);
```

`1000` é o tempo a ser esperado em millisegundos.